Almost sure convergence of random variable series with indicator
Let $S_k-S_{k-1}\sim_{iid} \exp(\lambda)$ where $S_0 = 0$ and define a quantity
$$X_t := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-S_k} \cdot 1_{\{S_k \leq t\}}$$
for every $t \geq 0$.
Does $X_t$ converge to a finite random variable almost surely, as $t \to \infty$?
Note: In the context of this problem $S_k$ is considered the $k$-th jump time for a Poisson process... However for the convergence of this RV I do not believe this is relevant.

What we want to show is
$$
P(\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} X_t = X) = 1
$$
We can define $X=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-S_k}$ as the pointwise limit for $X_t$. Thus what we are looking for is
$$
P(\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty (e^{-S_k}\cdot 1_{S_k \leq t} - e^{-S_k}\cdot 1_{S_k < \infty}) = 0) = P(\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-S_k}\cdot 1_{S_k > t} = 0) = 1
$$
We can see that $\sum_{k=1}^n (S_k - S_{k-1})$ is a telescoping sum that is equal to $S_n - S_0 = S_n$ and therefore distributed as $Gamma(n, \lambda)$. Furthermore, what we really care about is the behavior of the indicator because as long as it is equal to 0 a.s. then we can guarentee convergence of the limit to 0...
But I am not sure how to show this formally.

Firstly, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} X_t = X$ almost surely for your given definition of $X$, by the monotone convergence theorem and because each $S_k$ is Gamma-distributed and therefore is is almost surely finite.
Using the Fubini-Tonelli theorem and the moment generating function of the exponential distribution,
$$\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb E[\exp(-S_k)] =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}\right)^k < \infty$$
so $X$ is finite almost surely.

Yeah, I think I see it for the limit and I see that it should also be finite. The thing that I am not convinced of is whether this occurs with probability 1 or how to approach showing that.
